How can I search with ChatGPT from the browser address bar?
How can I add ChatGPT as a search engine in my browser, with the search mode enabled?

Add a custom search engine in your browser settings, using the following format:

https://chatgpt.com/?q=%s&hints=search&temporary-chat=true

The parameters are as follows:

q: the input query
hints: set this to 'search' to enable the internet search mode in ChatGPT
temporary-chat: prevent this query from being saved and cluttering your ChatGPT history

P.S. I'm answering my own question because as of December 2024, this information is very hard to find. Even ChatGPT 4o didn't know the answer. Credit to Muatex and Wells
